# Oracle APEX (v19.1.0.00.15) does not fetch raw datatype

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a table with an id field type of guid/raw(32) as FK.
I created an "Drill Down" page with page wizzard. The wizzard does not put this id field to the edit page. I put it manually but the generated fetch process does not fetch value into it. The page saving works well, include this field. I also test the page with another manually inserted but different field type, it's also works. For testing also created an "Report with Form", and it also works well. It use another method, not fetch process. Is there any trick to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by creating a "Drill Down" page? This is not the name of an option in the Create Page Wizard. I tested "Master Detail" and like "Report with Form", it worked fine.

Comment: I mean [Drill Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFOib.jpg)

Comment: Ah, that's a Master Detail page (Drill Down type). When you say the " The wizzard does not put this id field to the edit page.", are you referring to the id of the parent or child table? Also, are you expecting users to edit RAW IDs converted to HEX or something? Why would you expose that field?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this behavior, but it seemed consistent with other regions, such as a Report with Form. I suppose this could be argued in different ways because RAW values can't really be displayed except as a bunch of ones and zeros which isn't really useful. You'd have to convert the value to something like HEX and APEX shouldn't have much of a say in how that's done.

A workaround that I had success with was to create a view on top of the table which does an explicit conversion of the RAW type to HEX using RAWTOHEX. Here's an example script:

```
create table p (
  id raw(16) default sys_guid() primary key,
  name varchar2(10) not null
);

create table c (
  id        raw(16) default sys_guid(),
  parent_id raw(16) not null
            constraint c_p_id_fk
            references p,
  name      varchar2(10) not null
);

declare

  l_p1_id raw(16);
  l_p2_id raw(16);
  l_p3_id raw(16);

begin

  insert into p (name) values ('p 1') returning id into l_p1_id;
  insert into p (name) values ('p 2') returning id into l_p2_id;
  insert into p (name) values ('p 3') returning id into l_p3_id;

  insert into c (parent_id, name) values (l_p1_id, 'c 1 p 1');
  insert into c (parent_id, name) values (l_p1_id, 'c 2 p 1');
  insert into c (parent_id, name) values (l_p2_id, 'c 3 p 2');
  insert into c (parent_id, name) values (l_p3_id, 'c 4 p 3');
  insert into c (parent_id, name) values (l_p3_id, 'c 5 p 3');
  insert into c (parent_id, name) values (l_p3_id, 'c 6 p 3');

end;
/

create view p_v
as
select rawtohex(id) as id,
  name
from p;
```

I then created the Master Detail page using the ROWID pseudo column instead of the PK column so that the PK field would be editable (though I'm still not sure why one would want to do this).